# How to provide set of predefined instructions in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface, pygame-tick

I am new to pygame and not a regular coder. I am trying to wright a pygame code which accepts set of instructions from a text box and then move the image accordingly. eg: When you execute the code the pygame window will open with a textbox & primary image. First the user will provide set of directions LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN. After the the primary image should travel LEFT > RIGHT > UP > DOWN.

Below is a try from my end but here the image is directly reaching to last step instead of moving one after the other.

I want the image to move A - B - C - D and not A - D directly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

# game screen dimensions
screen_width = 1200
screen_height = 800

# Define colors for using it in code
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
dark_red = (138,0,0)
green = (0,128,0)
dark_green = (0,200,0)
silver = (192,192,192)


display_mygame = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))

# Primary Image
my_img = pygame.image.load('kid.png')

def game_loop():
    x = (screen_width * 0.25)
    y = (screen_height * 0.8)
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    input_box = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 240, 62)
    color_inactive = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')
    color_active = pygame.Color('dodgerblue2')
    color = color_inactive
    active = False
    text = ''
    list = []
    count = 0
    start_width = 50
    start_height = 50
    sy = 0
    crashed = False
    while not crashed:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            display_mygame.fill(white)
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if input_box.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    active = not active
                else:
                    active = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if active:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                        # Capturing the 4 instructions provided
                        list.append(str(text))
                        text = ""
                        count += 1
                        # Want the primary image to act accordingly to the instructions
                        if int(count) == 4:
                            for text in list:
                                if text == 'left':
                                    x += -300
                                elif text == 'right':
                                    x += 450
                                elif text == 'up':
                                    y += -300
                                elif text == 'down':
                                    y += 300

                    elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                        text = text[:-1]
                    else:
                        text += event.unicode
        display_mygame.blit(my_img, (x,y))
        txt_surface = font.render(text, True, color)
        width = max(200, txt_surface.get_width()+10)
        input_box.w = width
        display_mygame.blit(txt_surface, (input_box.x+5, input_box.y+5))
        pygame.draw.rect(display_mygame, color, input_box, 2)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not name a variable [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list). For instance use the name `move_list` rather than `list`.

Add 2 new states, `walking` and `move`:

```py
walking = False
move = [0, 0]
```

Do not accept any input if `walking == True`. Set `walking = True` if the number of inputs is 4:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        quit()

    if not walking:
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if input_box.collidepoint(event.pos):
                active = not active
            else:
                active = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if active:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    # Capturing the 4 instructions provided
                    move_list.append(str(text))
                    text = ""
                    count += 1
                    walking = count == 4
                elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    text = text[:-1]
                else:
                    text += event.unicode
```

Move the player in the main application loop, if `walking == True`. Remove the first element from `move_list` and set the moving direct `move` accordingly. If `move` is set move the player by 1 in every frame and appropriate decrease `move`:

```py
if walking:
    if move[0] != 0 or move[1] != 0:
        if move[0] < 0:
            x -= 1
            move[0] += 1
        if  move[0] > 0:
            x += 1
            move[0] -= 1
        if move[1] < 0:
            y -= 1
            move[1] += 1
        if  move[1] > 0:
            y += 1
            move[1] -= 1
    elif len(move_list) > 0:
        if move_list[0] == 'left':
            move = [-300, 0]
        elif move_list[0] == 'right':
            move = [300, 0]
        elif move_list[0] == 'up':
            move = [0, -300]
        elif move_list[0] == 'down':
            move = [0, 300]
        del move_list[0]
    else:
        walking = False
        count = 0
```

See the example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

# game screen dimensions
screen_width = 1200
screen_height = 800

# Define colors for using it in code
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
dark_red = (138,0,0)
green = (0,128,0)
dark_green = (0,200,0)
silver = (192,192,192)


display_mygame = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))

# Primary Image
#my_img = pygame.image.load('kid.png')
my_img = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
my_img.fill((0, 255, 0))

def game_loop():
    x = (screen_width * 0.25)
    y = (screen_height * 0.8)
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    input_box = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 240, 62)
    color_inactive = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')
    color_active = pygame.Color('dodgerblue2')
    color = color_inactive
    active = False
    text = ''
    move_list = []
    count = 0
    start_width = 50
    start_height = 50
    sy = 0
    crashed = False
    walking = False
    move = [0, 0]
    while not crashed:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if not walking:
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if input_box.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        active = not active
                    else:
                        active = False
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if active:
                        if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                            # Capturing the 4 instructions provided
                            move_list.append(str(text))
                            text = ""
                            count += 1
                            walking = count == 4
                        elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                            text = text[:-1]
                        else:
                            text += event.unicode

        if walking:
            if move[0] != 0 or move[1] != 0:
                if move[0] < 0:
                    x -= 1
                    move[0] += 1
                if  move[0] > 0:
                    x += 1
                    move[0] -= 1
                if move[1] < 0:
                    y -= 1
                    move[1] += 1
                if  move[1] > 0:
                    y += 1
                    move[1] -= 1
            elif len(move_list) > 0:
                if move_list[0] == 'left':
                    move = [-300, 0]
                elif move_list[0] == 'right':
                    move = [300, 0]
                elif move_list[0] == 'up':
                    move = [0, -300]
                elif move_list[0] == 'down':
                    move = [0, 300]
                del move_list[0]
            else:
                walking = False
                count = 0


        display_mygame.fill(white)
        display_mygame.blit(my_img, (x,y))
        txt_surface = font.render(text, True, color)
        width = max(200, txt_surface.get_width()+10)
        input_box.w = width
        display_mygame.blit(txt_surface, (input_box.x+5, input_box.y+5))
        pygame.draw.rect(display_mygame, color, input_box, 2)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: I want to add new line after every input the user has typed. instead of text = "". I am providing text = text + "\n" but this is not working. Is there a simpler way to achieve this ?

Comment: @vivs No, you have to render each line separately.